# Help with running pr2_simulator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to run pr2 in gazebo but when i tried rosmake pr2_teleop
i an error-

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pr2_teleop']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/nachum/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120903-142444
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pr2_teleop'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['pr2_teleop']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

how should i run the teleop?
Thanks
Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42813/help-with-running-pr2_simulator/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

o.k i found it
you write:
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/pr2apps/pr2_apps ppp
and then rosmake pr2_teleop
and it works

---

Originally posted by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) with karma: 208 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-02-06**:
it doesn't work